# Rectification voltage

Tags: power-supply, bridge-rectifier

I designed this power supply and simulated in Multisim 13.0, and noticed that the output of the full bridge was higher than that of the input to it. Would this have anything to do with the electrolytic cap in parallel with the out of the bridge? I'm unsure to why this is happening. Any help is appreciated. Thanks! [image]

Comment: I suspect that the AC voltage measurement is RMS.  This means the peak is actually sqrt(2) times that level.

Comment: That actually makes so much sense now, thank you !

Answer (score 3):

The 24 V AC voltage you are measuring is 24 V<sub>RMS</sub> or root-mean squared. It is the equivalent DC voltage that will give the same heating power into a load. It's peak voltage is √2V<sub>RMS</sub>.

The rectifier and smoothing capacitors will give √2 x 24 = 34 V. You will lose 2 x 0.7 V on the diodes so that results in 32.6 V.

When you load up the circuit the DC voltage will fall as the capacitor will discharge somewhat while the AC voltage is low.